# Value stop changing once saved to an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, reference

I have a React App with a localization object and a current language in global state, e.g:

```
const locale = {
  eng: {
    test: "English"
  },
  esp: {
    test: "Spanish"
  },
  ger: {
    test: "German"
  }
};
```

If I render text and change the language, the text will change as it should. However, if I save the value to an array, then the value in the array stops changing when the language changes.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      array: [],
      lang: "eng"
    };
  }

  get locale() {
    return locale[this.state.lang];
  }

  setLocale = (lang) => {
    this.setState({ lang });
  };

  saveToArray = (caption) => {
    const newArray = [...this.state.array, { caption }];
    this.setState({ array: newArray });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>From app: {this.locale.test}</div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setLocale("eng")}>English</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.setLocale("esp")}>Spanish</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.setLocale("ger")}>German</button>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.saveToArray(this.locale.test)}>
            save to array
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>Array: {this.state.array.map(el => el.caption)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-yz6hls?file=/index.js

Why is this happening? What needs to be done so that the text changes after being saved to the array?

I tried to pass the value in the object:

```
  saveToArray = (caption) => {
    const newArray = [...this.state.array, { caption: {str: caption} }];
    this.setState({ array: newArray });
  };
```

and through the function (and then call the function when rendering):

```
saveToArray = (caption) => {
    const captionFn = (caption) => return caption;
    const newArray = [...this.state.array, { caption: () => captionFn(caption) }];
    this.setState({ array: newArray });
  };
```

It didn't help.

Comment: It is changing in sandbox for me atleast even after saving to array

Comment: The value in the 4th line, after the words "Array:"? It doesn't change after it was saved.

Comment: Yes, the value in 4th line after the words "Array:", it is changing

Comment: strange, it doesn't work for me, here's a GIF
https://gifyu.com/image/SQlY1

Comment: `However, if I save the value to an array, then it stops changing when the language changes.` What is `it`? I assumed it's text in front of `Array:`